# My cat Has No sound when it meows, but puurs VERY loudly. Confusion!

Tags: cats, vocalizations

My cat is around 14 Years old and has switched between outside and inside most of its life.
When we first had Our cat He was often outside.
That was until one day he got a scratch on his nose and for some reason never went out again

My family have moved since then and we often let him out for 2 days, then bring him back and depending on what he wants, he only stays for around 2-3 days.
I always wonder now,
Why is there no sound when he meows?
He does stand at the door and 'meow' but theres no sound!
So its a guess and go, if he (supposedly) wants food, we'll bring him to the kitchen, we let the food down..And boom! turns out he wanted to go outside.
He purrs VERY loudly and often so im confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually common enough for cats to meow with no human-audible sound that there are [resources](https://www.hillspet.com/cat-care/behavior-appearance/why-do-cats-silently-meow) written on the subject. Some cats, like mine, will not fully voice their meows only some of the time. When my cat does it, I can actually hear his breath though. It seems cats that do this are in fact making noise; it's just not loud enough for humans to really hear it. The loudness of your cat's purr is somewhat unrelated, as the purr is produced by a different part of the anatomy from the meow.